A special Hamel basis and a special additive function
On mathstackexchange I recently
asked
whether for an irrational number $a$ a special Hamel basis of type $\bigcup_{i\in I}\{x_i,y_i,ay_i\}$ exists,
where $x_i, y_i$ and $ay_i$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearily independent. It still remains without any answer or comments. So I would like to ask here the seemingly related  question whether there exists a non-$\mathbb R$-linear additive function $f$ such that
for all $x\in \mathbb R$ one has $f(ax)= af(x)$. Note that of course $f(rx)=rf(x)$ for any rational number $r$.

$\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ so there is a $\mathbb{Q}(a)$-linear function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is not $\mathbb{R}$-linear

Using the structure over $\mathbb Q(a)$ a bit more we can also construct a basis as at the start of your question. I've written that up as an answer to your MSE question.

@user49822 Nice idea from number theory using this bigger field $\mathbb Q(a)$.
